# How can I attach a database to an app in Heroku?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I'm using Heroku's Postgres addon, and I created a new production database from the Heroku Postgres addon page.
I Didn't add it directly to my App using the Resources page of my App.

Now I want to attach this database to my App so it'll be recognized by the **heroku pg** command.

I'm able to use the database btw after setting the **DATABASE_URL** config var of my app to point to it, but **heroku pg** command doesn't recognize it yet.

Additional info: The previous database was Shared, and the new one is a Production.

Answer (score 13):

> Heroku add-ons may now be attached across applications and multiple times on a single app.

```
heroku addons:attach ADDON_NAME -a APP_NAME
```

*Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/646*

---

To know the name of your addon, do:

```
heroku addons
```

*Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons*

Comment: This is a better answer than the most-upvoted @rdegges answer from 2012, because Heroku will sometimes change the database URL, perhaps after an outage or other maintenance action.

Comment: Of you want to set the new DB as default, you have to promote it, something like `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX --app app_destination`

Answer (score 12):

Did you add the database using the app-independent https://postgres.heroku.com/ site? Or did you just create a postgresql database in your Heroku control panel?

If you created your database on https://postgres.heroku.com/, you will *not* see the database via your `heroku pg:info` command. What you can do to add your database to your application, however, would be to:

1. Log into https://postgres.heroku.com/.
2. Click on the database you want to attach to your application.
3. Under 'Connection Settings', click the configuration button at the top right.
4. Then click the 'URL' option.
5. Copy your database URL, this should be something like "postgres://blah:blah@ec2-23-23-122-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/omg".
6. In your application, on the command line, run `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://blah:blah@ec2-23-23-122-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/omg`

What we did there was assign your database to the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable in your application. This is the variable that's used by default when you provision databases locally to your application, so theoretically, assigning this value should work just fine for you.

Comment: Well, I already did that and the database is working fine with the App. My problem is that the **pg** command can't see it, even with the **DATABASE_URL** config var set to point to the new production database.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me after upgrading from the Hobby-dev to Hobby-basic

Comment: There's an official method for that: https://blog.heroku.com/expanding_the_power_of_add_ons

Comment: Thanks @MeoriOransky , this is exactly what I was looking for: `heroku addons:attach my-sushi-db -a my-sushi-reporting --as MAIN_SUSHI_DB` (in this example, `my-sushi-reporting` is the app that the database will be attached to)

Answer (score 1):

To get your database that you created at https://postgres.heroku.com/ attached to your actual heroku app that you are working on you can't use any of the [pg backup commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) and as far as I can tell there is no supported Heroku way of attaching a database to a heroku app.

You can however create a backup of your database using pg_dump and then use pg_restore to populate your new database that is attached to your app:

```
pg_dump -i -h hostname -p 5432 -U username -F c -b -v -f "backup-filename" database_name
```

Once that is complete you can populate your new database with:

```
pg_restore -i -h new_hostname -p 5432 -U new_username -d new_database_name -v "same_backup_filename"
```

Even if you are upgrading from the "basic plan" to a the "crane plan" you still have to do a backup and restore, but since the db's are already attached to your app you have the advantage of using the heroku backup commands.