# Heroku Problems: Not able to deploy app for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I am trying to deploy a basic app from Github to Heroku.

Following directions from [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app)

Here's the thing. When I clone from the github repository, I clone a specific branch that's 8 commits ahead of master.

The reason why I clone that specific branch is that it's the most advanced on. Each branch is built upon the previous branch.

I don't want to merge that branch into the master because I don't know how to undo that.

By the time I try to do this step from the guide above: `heroku ps:scale web=1`, I always get this: `Scaling dynos... failed
 !     App must be deployed before dynos can be scaled.`

Why does this happen? Advice?

Please let me know if this question needs further clarification. Thank you.

EDIT

For the record, it has the Procfile which has this in it: `web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`

EDIT 2

When I do `git push heroku branch_name` - this is what I get:

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (243/243), done.
Writing objects: 100% (389/389), 727.55 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 389 (delta 111), reused 389 (delta 111)
remote: Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.
```

EDIT 3

I followed the first answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700602/how-can-i-attach-a-database-to-an-app-in-heroku).

It worked, and restarted the app in Heroku.

But I restarted it again with this line: `heroku restart --app name_of_app_in_heroku` and got this: `Restarting dynos... done`

Then I tried to do `heroku open --app name_of_app_in_heroku`, and all I get is the basic welcome page. How do I overcome this?

Also, I just looked at my Heroku's dashboard, and checked the app, and it says it has no dynos. How is that possible?

EDIT 4

Also, I just ran this command: `heroku pg:info` and got this answer: `name_of_app_in_heroku has no heroku-postgresql databases.`

But that shouldn't be, I can see the DB's URL in the app's config vars in the settings of the app's dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the app's never been deployed (because you're trying to deploy non master branch and heroku has been ignoring the pushes)

When you push to heroku, the name for the branch needs to be master on the heroku side.

By default `git push` keeps the same name for both sides:

```
git push heroku some_branch
```

Tries to (assuming upstream is setup appropriately etc) update a branch called "some_branch" on the heroku remote, with your local branch of the same name.

To use a different name you'd do

```
git push heroku some_branch:master
```

Which means push the changes from the branch called some_branch locally to heroku's master branch

Comment: thanks. (blah blah blah added here for the required extra characters!)

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your app try doing this

```
 gp heroku master -f
 heroku run rake db:migrate --app APPNAME
 heroku restart --app APPNAME
 heroku open --app APPNAME
```

This are the lines that I use when I deploy a project to Heroku

Comment: just saw your answer. Before I run your lines, you did see the part where I said that I'm not deploying from master branch but from a branch that's 8 commits ahead? Double-checking because I'm a little worried what would happen if this backfires.

Comment: how far ahead is your app than what is on heroku?

Comment: what's on the app is on the Heroku, i.e., the cloned branch from Github. That's why I do `git push heroku` instead of `git push heroku master`

Comment: when I said it's 8 commits ahead, I'm referring to Github. Hence me trying to push up a cloned branch to Heroku.

Comment: for what it's worth, when I push the cloned branch to Heroku, it seems to work.

Comment: I just added a 2nd edit to my post. In case this affects your answer. Please let me know if it does.

Comment: huh, I just tried the first line `gp heroku master -f`, and got this `-bash: gp: command not found`

Comment: tried second line `heroku run rake db:migrate --app APPNAME` and got this: `Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... failed
 !    App not found`